# How do I Get Websphere to Propagate keystore changes from The Deployment manager to the nodes?

Tags: ssl, websphere, keystore

I'm a bit stumped on this one.

I had a completely working 2 Node cluster, changed the keystore and the truststore to use different files, saved the changes.

My assumption was that the deployment manager would automatically propagate those changes to the nodes before switching over.
However according to the deployment manager, the nodes are now no longer running, and looking at the logs it's getting a lot of ssl errors trying to connect to them.

Now how do I proceed? The dep mgr can't even talk to the node agents, how is it going to give them the new ssl changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oop,  Looks like I jumped on the lazyweb too quickly.

As with numerous websphere problems, restarting the nodes and the dmgr 4 or 5 times solved it.

Comment: I usually find it best when making changes on the dmgr to just call syncNodes just to be sure the changes get propogated.